# How do I configure my XP to look like that (link inside!)?

Tags: themes, user-interface, desktop-customization

I fell in love [with this desktop](http://harrybana.deviantart.com/art/desky-sept-1-135530489), I want to reproduce it. Although he mentions the themes and applications used I have no idea how to do it.

Any guides, tutorials, how-to's that brings me closer to it are highly appreciated!

Comment: Umm.. I think the artist's comments are all you need. Perhaps if you could specify what is exactly you need help with you might get some useful answers.

Comment: Copy that image and use it as your desktop wallpaper. Adjust your monitor resolution to the size of that image. Hide the desktop icons and make your taskbar auto-hide too. Your desktop will now look like his. It won't function like his, though. It just looks like his. Which reminds me of when I made a screenshot of a dialog box, which I added to my wallpaper image. It really annoys other people who use my system.

Answer (score 5):

Everything is written in the artist's comments below...

Comment: No, it isn't. I'm looking for a HOW-TO not "What Applications"..

Comment: Well then why don't you "USE" the applications given? Putting the tool bar to the top should be easy, the wall paper to. The "Dock" app you will have to use.

Comment: @NoCanDo Uh, the HOW-TO is pretty clearly implied. Install the applications and the themes the artist mentions. Select those themes. Done!

Comment: Yah, you have to just install the apps mentioned. That is how they modified the OS.

Comment: Oh, well I haven't started yet so I assumed I had to do more than that. Well, I'm off to try it then..

Comment: NoCanDo find links? :)

Answer (score 5):

download and install this:

1. [Zune Theme for XP](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Themes/Microsoft-Zune-Theme.shtml)
2. [ViOrb - Vista start button for XP](http://lee-soft.com/viorb/)
3. [Rocketdock - Application Launcher](http://rocketdock.com/)

make sure your taskbar isn't locked, then drag it to the top of the screen and place Rocketdock at the bottom. grab the [wallpaper](http://harrybana.deviantart.com/art/Floor-painted-Red-120823131) and use your image editor of choice to change the hue colour to blue, reduce the contrast to your likings, save it and set as desktop background.

edit: in case you NoCanDo wallpaper, [here](http://i365.photobucket.com/albums/oo94/eeemolly/nocando1680x1050.jpg) it is ready to go (1680x1050) as suggested by the creator of the theme. :)